# First character missing from bufferedreader of socket

Tags: java, sockets, bufferedreader

I am reading a string from a bufferedreader of a socket but the first character keeps going missing.

The only time I read from the stream is when I store it in the string dummy. So I don't understand why the first character would go missing.

I thought it might be something in the processMessage function which might be causing it, but I commented that line out and ran the code again and the first character still went missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverTCP.getInputStream()));    

    while(true){

        try{
            //try and read the message and process it

            String dummy = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("received message1: " + dummy);
            processMessage(dummy);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }



    }
```

Comment: Add the code that writes it on the server side to the question.

Comment: And explain to us how this code is supposed to terminate. You need to test the result of `readLine()` for null.